# PHP Form Submission: "false" not passed in

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I have a form that inserts user input into a MySQL database, and one of the input field has a Boolean value. It works fine when the value is true, however if the value is false, my 'echo' and database can't receive that value at all. I really have no idea what's happening. Please take a look at my code below: 
HTML:

```
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="consentForEmail" name="consentForEmail" />&nbsp;
                  <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">By clicking this button I agree to receive emails from us</span>
                </label>
```

JavaScript for collecting and setting the value:

```
    var _this = '#consentForEmail';

    $('#consentForEmail').change(function(){
      var checked = $('#consentForEmail').prop('checked');
      $(_this).val(checked);
      console.log( $('#consentForEmail').val() );
    });
```

And finally, PHP for collecting form data:

```
$receive_email = $_POST["consentForEmail"];
echo "<li>$receive_email</li>"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Checkbox transmits either as ON or doesn't transmit at all. It does not send over true and false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes do not submit along with the form if they're not checked, no matter what their value is. While you CAN have a value attached to the checkbox `<input>`, the real test for being checked is whether the input's `name` appears at all:

```
if (isset($_POST['consentForEmail'])) { 
   ... box was checked 
} else {
   ... box was NOT checked
}
```